# curl request with authorization header in R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

```
curl --include \
     --header "Authorization: Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj" \
     "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications?app_id={appId}"
```

I am looking at RCurl package but fail to understand a way to include the header above in api call. I would like to know how to include this header in my api call in R.

Comment: Does [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html#customizing_requests) cover it?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Show your R code and we can point out what the problem might be.

Comment: @Mako212: Thanks. that helped. How do I data out of this response: Response [https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications?app_id=b0ccd71c-f70e-421d-a0ee-c00d58a5bd85]
  Date: 2018-01-04 19:33
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 86.6 kB

Answer (score 3):

I have used curl package instead  RCURL to this.

My goal was to CURL GET request with **headers** from OANDA to obtain price response.

**The curl command I intend to run:**

```
curl \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ****api_key***" \
  "https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{account_id}/instruments?instruments=EUR_USD"
```

**R equivalent:**

```
library(curl)
h <- new_handle(verbose = TRUE)
handle_setheaders(h,
 "Content-Type" = "application/json",
 "Authorization" = "Bearer ****api_key****"
)
con <- curl("https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{account_id}/instruments?instruments=EUR_USD", handle = h)
jsonlite::prettify(readLines(con))
```

Output:

```
    "instruments": [
        {
            "name": "EUR_USD",
            "type": "CURRENCY",
            "displayName": "EUR/USD",
            "pipLocation": -4,
            "displayPrecision": 5,
            "tradeUnitsPrecision": 0,
            "minimumTradeSize": "1",
            "maximumTrailingStopDistance": "1.00000",
            "minimumTrailingStopDistance": "0.00050",
            "maximumPositionSize": "0",
            "maximumOrderUnits": "100000000",
            "marginRate": "0.02",
            "guaranteedStopLossOrderMode": "DISABLED",
            "tags": [
                {
                    "type": "ASSET_CLASS",
                    "name": "CURRENCY"
                }
            ],
            "financing": {
                "longRate": "-0.0178",
                "shortRate": "-0.0031",
                "financingDaysOfWeek": [
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "MONDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "FRIDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "SATURDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
                        "daysCharged": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "lastTransactionID": "3"
}
```